# Zookeeper/Curator can't lock same path twice

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have a distributed system that needs to 'lock' (if that's the right term) a resource "/dev/resource1".  That lock needs to exist for some hours, then be released. The release may be in a different thread or JVM.  That JVM may have died.

I tried using:

```
    public boolean createLocks(ArrayList<String> paths) {
    InterProcessMultiLock mutex = new InterProcessMultiLock(client, paths );
    try{
         boolean works = mutex.acquire(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
         return works;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
public boolean releaseLocks(List<String> path) {
    try{
        InterProcessMultiLock mutex = new InterProcessMultiLock(client, path );
         mutex.release();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

but the second time I locked the same path, it failed.

```
assertTrue("Creating simple lock", adapter.createLocks(locks) );
assertTrue("Releasing simple lock.", adapter.releaseLocks(locks) );
assertTrue("Creating simple lock", adapter.createLocks(locks) ); //Fails
```

> java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: You do not own the lock: /aamm/unittest/locktest/1472646694110

What am I missing?  Is there something else I should be using?  Should I just create nodes and not fool around with locks?

Comment: Maybe it would help to use the same lock for all acquire and release operations, rather than creating new locks…

Comment: I have tens of thousands of potential locks.  It's essentially either a serial number or an id for a group of serial numbers.  I need to only process one message per group, and filter all the others out.  This way, the first one in creates a node and all the others fail to create it.

Comment: It seems that wordy comment misses the point. Your `releaseLocks` method creates a new `InterProcessMultiLock` instance, instead of invoking `release()` on the instance created and locked in `createLocks`. Of course, trying to release that freshly created, unlocked instance will provoke a `You do not own the lock` error. Apparently, you also failed to recognize that the release operation failed; you never get to the second locking attempt.

Comment: This is where I'm confused.  Do locks outlive the parent process?  

After some more research, I changed the approach and created a znode in the createLocks, then removed it in the releaseLocks.  Now I have to manage the collections of locks myself, but the nodes outlive the thread and JVM deaths, and trying to add an existing node fails. 

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I don’t know how this `InterProcessMultiLock` achieves its inter-process functionality, but this isn’t relevant here. Here, you fail to maintain the lock ownership *within* the process.